# how to encrypt Smooth Streaming with PlayReady

Tags: drm, smooth-streaming, playready

I am trying to develop an encryption tools that takes clear Smooth Streaming files and encrypt them with PlayReady DRM.

The only solution I found is using IIS Transform Manager.
My problem is that I want an offline tool without any dependency to IIS.
I already have my tool encrypting regular files, and I want to achieve that for SS as well..

Any tool/lib you know?

Thanks

Comment: What tool do you use for encrypting regular files? I assume you refer to WMV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS Transform Manager comes with a tool called SmoothProtect, which is a command-line utility that can do exactly what you need. In addition, it has a redistribution license, so you can use the tool separately from IIS Transform Manager.

You can find this tool at `%programfiles%\IIS\Transform Manager\SmoothProtect.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You could user Azure Media Services to encrypt Smooth Streaming file with PlayReady license, here is how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQCM1jFdi_4. You could either use PlayReady license server provided in the cloud, or set up your own PlayReady license server.

Meanwhile, Azure Media Services offer dynamic decryption capability that encrypt stream on the fly. For more information please refer to my blog post: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/10/announcing-public-availability-of-azure-media-services-content-protection-services/.